# Script changes mail attachment name (powershell)

Tags: powershell, email

Heyho,

so my script I use to send out VPN certificates changes the name of the `.zip` file to `.zi_` and I don't get why.

If I run it a second time, there is no problem and it sends the Attachment with `.zip`, also the actual name of the file isn't changed (so in the folder there isn't a `.zi_` file).

Here is the code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\VPN\20170828\*.zip
ForEach ($file in $files) {
$mail =$file.Name.TrimEnd("-cert.zip")
Compress-Archive -Path C:\VPN\run-me.bat, C:\VPN\vpn.ovpn -DestinationPath $file -Update
Send-MailMessage -From mail@mail.com -Subject "VPN Cert" -To $mail -Attachments $file -SmtpServer mail.server.com -Body $mailbody -Bcc mail@mail.com
}
```

The Script adds the _"run_me.bat"_ and the *"vpn.ovpn*" to the zip. 
The name of the file is like this: `max.mustermann@company.com-cert.zip`.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Edit:

So I changed it a bit to test:

```
echo "Mail: " $mail.ToString();
echo "File: " $file.ToString();
Send-MailMessage -From mail@mail.com -Subject "VPN Cert" -To $mail -Attachments $file -SmtpServer mail.server.com -Body $mailbody -Bcc mail@mail.com
echo "File again" $file
```

the output is:

```
Mail: 
Mail@company.com
File: 
C:\VPN\other\Mail@company.com-cert.zip
File again


    Directory: C:\VPN\other


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                         
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                         
-a----       30.08.2017     15:24           8705 Mail@company.com-cert.zip
```

But still I get the mail with `.zi_`

I really don't get why. 
Also this exact script worked for month and then it did this.

Comment: So at the destination it's showing up as `.zi_`?  What about locally? is it being updated to `C:\VPN\etc\*.zip` or `*.zi_`?

Comment: Yes, in the Mail the attachment is named something.zi_  locally the file is still named .zip

Comment: Try specifying the correct member; it might be trying to interpret because you're passing it a file object.  `-Attachments $file.FullName`

Comment: Didn't change anything, it's always just the first time I run this script in Powershell.